# How to create all combinations of multiple select tags which auto generates product ID and price of company?

Tags: jquery, combinations

I am web scraping products information of a electric manufacturer. The product page contains multiple select tags , selecting options from multiple select tags generate different price and product ID , the select tags also give information like volatage , color , ports ..etc. in their text.
For example

```
<select name="PowerSupply" onchange="changeList(....)">
<option value="69">H - 125/250 V AC/DC power supply</option>
<option value="70">L - 24/48 V DC power supply</option>
</select>

<select name="Mounting" onchange="changeList(....)">
<option value="44">H - Horizontal </option>
<option value="45">V - Vertical </option>
</select>
```

Changing the option in the multiple select auto changes Product ID and Price columns.

What technique can be used to create combinations of multiple select options , there are minimum five select tags.

Comment: Someone please answer its serious .

Comment: What i want is to create combinations of multiple select tags to generate different output.